# unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, sqlite, syntax-error

I am expecting this to be a basic syntax error I overlooked, but I can't figure it out.

In a PHP script, I keep getting the following error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in [path]/scripts/users/database_connection.php on line 4
```

This occurs when my script to connect to the database is called with an `include_once()`.  I stripped my script down to the most basic code (leaving in what is required by other code), and it still is calling this error.

```
<?php
    class UserDatabaseConnection
    {
        $connection = sqlite_open("[path]/data/users.sqlite", 0666);
        public function lookupUser($username)
        {
            // rest of my code...
        }
    }

    $udb = new UserDatabaseConnection;
?>
```

I have struggled with this for a while, and just wondered if anyone else could spot somewhere I went wrong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can not put

`$connection = sqlite_open("[path]/data/users.sqlite", 0666);`

outside the class construction. You have to put that line inside a function or the constructor but you can not place it where you have now.

Comment: @Rhino , its aright. @Lekensteyn has done a wonderful job and shows you how you should ideally do it.

Comment: Downvoted for conflation of terms `function` and `method`, and presupposition assignments cannot be made outside a class constructor.

Answer (score 23):

You cannot use function calls in a class construction, you should initialize that value in the constructor function.

From the [PHP Manual on class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization **must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

A working code sample:

```
<?php
    class UserDatabaseConnection
    {
        public $connection;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->connection = sqlite_open("[path]/data/users.sqlite", 0666);
        }
        public function lookupUser($username)
        {
            // rest of my code...
            // example usage (procedural way):
            $query = sqlite_exec($this->connection, "SELECT ...", $error);
            // object oriented way:
            $query = $this->connection->queryExec("SELECT ...", $error);
        }
    }

    $udb = new UserDatabaseConnection;
?>
```

Depending on your needs, `protected` or `private` might be a better choice for `$connection`. That protects you from accidentally closing or messing with the connection.

Answer (score 7):

Use access modifier before the member definition:

```
    private $connection;
```

As you cannot use function call in member definition in PHP, do it in constructor:

```
 public function __construct() {
      $this->connection = sqlite_open("[path]/data/users.sqlite", 0666);
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

put public, protected or private before the $connection.

Comment: Why is it need ?

Answer (score -1):

check that you entered a variable as argument with the '$' symbol

Answer (score -1):

We should keep our content inside public/private functions only. We can keep content outside of a function.